# Forward individual members of a Forward reference

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, class-members, forwarding-reference

I have a function that potentially moves a generic argument but through their members. What of these options is more correct:

1. This seems the more natural but it is strange because the argument is potentially moved twice [a], which is odd because the object can become invalid.

   ```
   template<class T> 
   void fun(T&& t){
       myhead_ = std::forward<T>(t).head_;
       myrest_ = std::forward<T>(t).rest_;
   }
   ```
2. This can't be incorrect but it may not be moving anything.

   ```
   template<class T> void fun(T&& t){
       myhead_ = std::forward<decltype(t.head_)>(t.head_);
       myrest_ = std::forward<decltype(t.rest_)>(t.rest_);
   }
   ```
3. This seems correct but too much code.

   ```
   template<class T> void fun(T& t){
       myhead_ = t.head_;
       myrest_ = t.rest_;
   }
   template<class T> void fun(T&& t){
       myhead_ = std::move(t.head_);
       myrest_ = std::move(t.rest_);
   }
   ```

---

[a] This statement is incorrect as @Angew pointed out, it only *looks* as if it is moved twice. `std::forward` (like `std::move`) doesn't actually move anything. At most the member is moved (by the subsequent operation `decltype(myhead)::operator=` but that is precisely the objective.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code is perfectly fine:

```
template<class T> 
void fun(T&& t){
    myhead_ = std::forward<T>(t).head_;
    myrest_ = std::forward<T>(t).rest_;
}
```

That is because the standard guarantees that when doing `a.b` and `a` is an xvalue (such as a forwarded rvalue reference), the result of `a.b` is also an exvalue (i.e. can be moved from). Also note that `std::forward` and `std::move` do not do any actual *moving* themselves, they're just casts. So there is no risk in moving from `t` twice in your code.

Comment: @alfC The second solution would never have moved, since `t.head_` is an lvalue (since `t` is an lvalue). You would have needed `std::forward` inside the decltype. However, I've since double-checked the standard and found that the whole thing is unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome, you might be interested in this related case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916134/225186 , which involve members functions instead of members by the idea is the same.