# Is there a technical reason why range-based for loop doesn't detect whether it's looping on an rvalue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics, rvalue, range-based-loop

The reason for the question is that I've seen code like this:

```cpp
auto fun(std::vector<Foo>&& v) {
    std::vector<Bar> w;
    for (auto&& e : v /* not an rvalue, but keep reading */) {
        w.push_back(std::move(e));
    }
    // do stuff with w
}
```

which is marked as erroneous by static analisys tools, as the forwarding reference `e` is being `std::move`d instead of being `std::forward`ed.

On the other hand, `v` binds for sure to a prvalue or an xvalue (something the client knows to be or wants `fun` to treat as a temporary), because its type is an rvalue reference. Yes, I see that the body of the function doesn't state in any way that `v` cannot be used after the `for` loop, but that would only lead me to think that I should change

- `for (auto&& e : v)` to `for (auto&& e : std::move(v))`,
- and `auto&&` to `E&&`, assuming something along the lines of `using E = std::decay_t<decltype(v)>::value_type;`.

As far as I've understood, the first point doesn't have the effect I would have expected. In fact, `std::move` seems to have no effect as far as the `for` is concerned. In turn, `e` keeps being initialized from an lvalue (at least if the frequent case that `operator[]` returns a reference for the type of `v`), and the second point simply causes a compilation error.

As an additional reference, the note `¹` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/5825294) reads (with reference to range-`for` loops)

> You cannot detect if you are iterating over a temporary (or other rvalue)

which seems to confirm that I just can't do that.

But looking at [how a range-`for` loop is desugared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation), what would be wrong in changing `range-declaration = *__begin;` to `range-declaration = std::move(*__begin);` when *`range-expression`* is an rvalue?

Comment: `std::forward` is used for perfect forwarding when you have argument controlled by deducible template parameter. `std::forward` is kind of smart version of `std::move`, so in your scenario it doesn't give anything.

Comment: `v` isn't an rvalue, it has a name so it is an lvalue.  You also can't gaurantee that `v` is bound to a temporary because you can do things like: `std::vector<Foo> bar = { stuff }; fun(std::move(bar));`

Comment: @NathanOliver, surely `v` isn't an rvalue, but `std::move(v)` is. As regards the temporary-ness of the argument corresponding to `v`, clearly the caller of `fun(std::move(bar))` knows they're saying "consider this a temporary".

Comment: `std::move(v)` is also not a temporary, as it returns a reference and all references are lvalues.

Comment: @NathanOliver, ok, I might have worded it wrong, but still `std::move(v)` is an xvalue, so with `std::move` I'm expressing that whatever I'm handing it too can steal stuff from it.

Comment: The fact that you can move a container doesn't mean you can move from it's contained values. See e.g. `std::set<>`, which has `const` keys.

Comment: @Enlico For most values, nothing would happen. (I do have classes around where it's different and where `T(const T&&)` is implemented, but it's only to avoid shared_ptr for it.) What I was raising, it's not a generic solution that solves the entire problem. Perhaps we could use a `std::for_each_move()` algorithm that containers could specialize...

Comment: Even if you manage to move `v`, `std::vector` does not have r-value overload for `begin()` or `end()`, so the issue is more with initialization of the begin/end iterator (for the standard snippet). Moving the iterator does not create a move iterator, it just creates an other standard iterator. What you would need here is a way to create a moveable view of your container where `begin()` and `end()` would return move iterator similar to `make_move_iterator`.

Comment: I'd suggest just write `std::move(v)` in your example for better clarity.

Comment: and I believe `*__begin` should return rvalue if *the iterator itself* see appropriate. a temporary container can pretty well held non-temporary data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the container is rvalue doesn't means what it contains is

```cpp
// note: in real code this could be T&& and have no idea it's a std::span
void foo(std::span<X>&& s){
    // explicitly std::move should be required
    // because the code may want to use `s` later
    for(auto&& v : std::move(s)){
        // if the for loop forward the value category of <range-expression> to items
        // then decltype(v) is X&&, and this wrongly move-out the data
        X t = std::forward<decltype(v)>(v); 
    }
}

int main(){
    X x[2];
    foo(x);
}
```

---

the decision should be done by

- the container itself, by return a [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)*
- by the user, where it can use [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like)
- or some adapter, for example `for(auto&& v : forward_content<...>(s))`

---

* the container/adaptor should always return `move_iterator`, overload for rvalue `begin`/`end` would not work in current standard, the normal one is always called. Plus [no standard container support them either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915905/move-iterators-for-containers).

Comment: So I guess that in c++17 and c++20 probably the most practical way is to give up on the range-based `for` and simply do `for (auto i = std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()); i != std::move_iterator(v.end()); ++i) {` so in the statement any `*i` will be an rvalue.

Comment: @Enlico I'd say the the most practical way is just `std::move` it. the static analyzer fail to recognize a correct pattern doesn't make it invalid.

Comment: Actually, would you clarify your first comment in the code? I don't understand what you're trying to say, as generally the wanting to be able to use an entity past an expression means I'm not `std::move`ing it in that expression.

Comment: @Enlico it's in respond of `/* not an rvalue, but keep reading */` in your question.

Comment: My comment was to say _since I'm not `std::move`ing `v`, I know I shouldn't even expect `auto&&` to resolve to `Foo&&`, but if you keep reading you'll see that even `std::move`ing `v`, `auto&&` keeps not being deduced as `Foo&&`_.

Comment: @Enlico yes I understood that correctly, I just point out that it will need `std::move` (or `std::forward`) *even after apply what you suggest*.