Why doesn't std::array<T,N>::operator[] return an rvalue reference for rvalue object?
std::array<T,N>::operator[] always returns an lvalue reference (const if needed), but what can possibly be the use of a line of code like this, which is valid C++?
std::array<int,1>{1}[0] = 3;

After all, std::get is a bit more strict, because if I write
std::get<0>(std::array<int, 1>{1}) = 3;

clang shouts at me

Expression is not assignable [typecheck_expression_not_modifiable_lvalue]

which incidentally makes me wonder "who's the lvalue??"; I mean, std::array<int, 1>{1} is an rvalue, and for rvalues std::get returns by rvalue reference, which means it returns an rvalue.
Anyway, I do understand that this behavior (of operator[]) also affects other containers, e.g. std::vector, but still, what was the benefit of such behavior, when these functions were standardized? And what is the benefit still today for not making a breaking change to the standard and just make operator[] behave like std::get?
I do understand that one can do
auto a = (std::array<int, 1>{1}[0] = 3);
assert(a == 3);

and I can imagine cases where one does something like that with a temporary std::vector<Foo>(10, 10) where the destructors of the Foos do something, but still...
Am I missing something more important?
Other than "if they do what you ask, then operator[] and std::get are synonymous".

I'm sure nobody bothered, that's all. Yes, separate && overloads would make sense, and C++23 "deducing this" would make this way easier.

looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311209/why-isnt-operator-overloaded-for-lvalues-and-rvalues

Looks like it might be a backwards compatibility requirement. It might be too late to implement for existing containers that were used in code before rvalue expressions existed without possibly breaking that code. std::get was added to the language in C++11, at the same time as rvalues so there would be no backwards compatibility issue to be concerned about in that case.

This all feels a lot like "the standard doesn't make breaking change because already broken code would break". Bah...

I for one think they would accept this if somebody made a proposal.

I think when rvalue references were introduced, things would have been broken in legacy code if API made consistent with value-ness. The same happened to other functions, begin() of rvalue containers still returns iterator, not move_iterator.
